# SigCgt value is not getting updated in /proc/<pid>/status file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals

I have read about the signal handling in linux processes. I am using centOS 7.1 (kernel 3.10+). I am registering handler only for **SIGTERM** in my c++ program. As per my knowledge(not sure if my assumptions are correct). We can check all the signals a process is listening to in **/proc/$pid/status** file by using SigCgt field mask. My process's **/proc/$pid/status** shows **SigCgt** field as below :-

```
SigCgt: 0000000184000200 ==> BitMask for this  ‭‭0001 1000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0010 0000 0000
```

As per my knowledge each bit corresponds to a signal. since **15th** bit which corresponds to SIGTERM is `1` in above mask. It indicates that signal handler for **SIGTERM** is registered.

My question is, **SigCgt** field value remains same even if I am not registering any signal handlers. Then how come few bits are set including **15th** bit(**which is for SIGTERM**) in **SigCgt** bitmask?

Any help is very much appreciated. I have already done enough googling but could not find any appropriate explanation.
Moreover It would be a great help If anyone can point me at right documentation or links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken about the SIGTERM bit. The first 16 bits of `0000000184000200` are given by `0200` which is `0000 0010 0000 0000`. The 15th bit (with lsb being bit #1) is `0`. The only bit on is #10 aka `SIGUSR1`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for correcting me here. :) All doubts are clear now. :)